# Why were my 2 edits suggesting formatting changes to numbering rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Please see https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/756634 and https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/756633. Adding numbering helped clarify the multitude of solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why was my edit, correcting a fact, rejected?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13075/why-was-my-edit-correcting-a-fact-rejected)

Comment: I think because the numbering is irrelevant, it does not contribute much to the post (the text is perfectly readable without the numbers). What's left is that you only added some white space/interpunction. People probably found that a marginal improvement.

Comment: @NordlysJeger Not a dupe. That one is about changing content, this is only about layout changes.

Answer (score 11):

Probably a few reasons. The reasons why I would have rejected them are, in no particular order:

1. The edits were *trivial* and neither clarified nor substantively improved the answers
2. The paragraphs you edited were not long enough to warrant breaking into two parts
3. Numbered lists work best as a list of steps to follow. You used them as little more than glorified line breaks separating the useful information.
4. Lists in general work best with some kind of explanation of why there is a list

   - "you need to follow these steps",
   - "try option 1 *or* option 2"

A final friendly observation... making an edit that gets rejected *and then redoing that exact same edit*, presumably in the hopes that you get different reviewers, is vaguely disingenuous to the community. It is very bad form.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

#### Edits should substantially improve posts.

From [Privileges - edit questions and answers - Super User](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/edit)

> Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.

Please also note than when you make an edit suggestion multiple other users have to review and approve/reject your suggestions.

In this case your edits where rejected by the reviewers with the reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

This is a good hint that the community feels your edits should be more substantial.